# Get revert reason from sendSignedTransaction

Tags: node.js, express, ethereum, web3js

I'm running a Hyperledger Besu private chain and making a sendSignedTransaction call from an Express server.

```
        try {
            let tx = {
                from: fromAccount,
                to: this.contract.options.address,
                gas: 2000000,
                gasPrice: "0",
                value: 0,
                data: await this.contract.methods
                    .method().encodeABI()
            };
    
            console.log(tx);
            console.log("signing transaction");
            let signedTx = await this.web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
            console.log("transaction signed");
            let result = await this.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
            console.log(result);
        }
        catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }
```

The transaction is reverting and being caught, but I'm not sure how to get the revert reason. I've tried setting `contract.handleRevert` as well as other solutions from search engines, but all the other solutions assume you are using `sendTransaction`,`call`, or `send` from the front end. Per the web3.js docs, handleRevert doesn't work for `sendSignedTransaction` (https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth.html#handlerevert) and the error returns as one long string:

```
Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "blockHash": "0xcb93d98a8d6f7c329dfd0cdb7d2fc421147ae077765e63263c794eb43aaa6263",
  "blockNumber": 560179,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 35348,
  "from": fromAddress,
  "gasUsed": 35348,
  "logs": [],
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "to": contractAddress,
  "transactionHash": "0xfbd9b755aa71d823640c0f719d358ef9c7d81362a901ec2901fba5f188a4a310",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "revertReason": "0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000204552433737373a2073656e6420746f20746865207a65726f2061646472657373"
}
    at Object.TransactionError (/home/blockchain-dev/Documents/blockchain-app/server/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:96:21)
    at Object.TransactionRevertedWithoutReasonError (/home/blockchain-dev/Documents/blockchain-app/server/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/src/errors.js:108:21)
    at /home/blockchain-dev/Documents/blockchain-app/server/node_modules/web3-core-method/src/index.js:482:48
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5) {
  receipt: {
    blockHash: '0xcb93d98a8d6f7c329dfd0cdb7d2fc421147ae077765e63263c794eb43aaa6263',
    blockNumber: 560179,
    contractAddress: null,
    cumulativeGasUsed: 35348,
    from: fromAccount,
    gasUsed: 35348,
    logs: [],
    logsBloom: '0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000',
    status: false,
    to: contractAddress,
    transactionHash: '0xfbd9b755aa71d823640c0f719d358ef9c7d81362a901ec2901fba5f188a4a310',
    transactionIndex: 0,
    revertReason: '0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000204552433737373a2073656e6420746f20746865207a65726f2061646472657373'
  }
}
```

I also tried running a hex to ascii converter on the revertReason hex code and the value was not readable.

I'd like to be able to get the revert reason for a sendSignedTransaction call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the `revertReason` using [web3.utils.hexToAscii()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-utils.html#hextoascii).

```
const reason = web3.utils.hexToAscii('0x08c379a0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000204552433737373a2073656e6420746f20746865207a65726f2061646472657373');
```

Returns

```
Ãy   ERC777: send to the zero address
```

Note: The first two characters look like UTF BOM, but [hexToUtf8()](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/web3-utils.html#hextoutf8) fails to decode the string (and the rest of the string is really ASCII, not UTF).

Comment: Though the TX is reverted, but there is no `revertReason` in  `receipt`, why it can happen and how to get the reason from receipt, without additional `eth.call(tx, tx.blockNumber)`?

Comment: When you setup the contract object, set the property handleRevert to true, and the revert reason will be returned in the receipt in hex. You will then need to convert it to ASCII

Answer (score 0):

This is a work around, since revertReason doesn't seem to work with sendSignedTransaction yet (at least from my experience using Alchemy's node service).

```
try {
    let tx = {
        from: fromAccount,
        to: this.contract.options.address,
        gas: 2000000,
        gasPrice: "0",
        value: 0,
        data: await this.contract.methods
            .method().encodeABI()
    };
    
    console.log(tx);
    console.log("signing transaction");
    let signedTx = await this.web3.eth.accounts.signTransaction(tx, privateKey);
    console.log("transaction signed");
    let result = await this.web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(signedTx.rawTransaction)
    console.log(result);
}
catch (e) {
    this.contract.methods.method()
        .call({'from': fromAccount}).then(() => {
        throw Error ('reverted tx')})
        .catch(revertReason => console.log({revertReason})
}
```